# Creating table containing contents of directory with FME 2014?

Tags: fme-form

I have to match the contents of a directory with the attributes of a FeatureClass. The FeatureClass field contains the names (without file endings) of documents which are either .pdf or .jpg files.

I have two directories - one for PDFs and the other for JPGs. I need to match the PDF file names with the FeatureClass Attribute and if they match rename them with the PDF file ending. The ones that are not matched are then obviously JPG.

How can I create the list of files using FME2014?

Comment: Is FME your only option here?  I can see this being done with python script.

Comment: Python is also an option if you have a solution - I was thinking more along the lines of the "Matcher" transformer though

Comment: What desktop GIS applications do you have (QGIS, ArcGIS, none...etc)?

Comment: Already done it with the "directory / path" reader...easy when you know how

Comment: Good to hear, please answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated in your comment, this can be done with a [Directory and File Pathnames Reader](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/path/PATH_reader.htm#CommonPathFilterIssues). In the reader parameters, you can set your Path Filter to only search PDF and JPG Files as so:

[image]

From there, you can join the results to your features using a [FeatureMerger](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featuremerger.htm) or [Matcher](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/matcher.htm) transformer, depending on your workflow.  You may need to do some string manipulation first, however.

Answer (score 0):

FilenamePartExtractor
Extracts specified parts of a filename path and returns the results as string attributes.

http://cdn.safe.com/resources/fme/FME-Transformer-Reference-Guide.pdf